# Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:

Tags: tkinter, macos-sonoma

2023-11-08 15:41:57.097 Python[4684:95290] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
Im not able to run tkinter programs on my macOS
Please help me with it

how to resolve this issue ?
Im facing this after I updated a new version of macOS Sonoma